When to update Yocto sstate-cache on CI server
Our Yocto CI script restores the sstate-cache on every build and updates it when bitbake succeeds via rsync. Our intention is to speed-up the CI builds by not rebuilding packages we already have.
The issue is that the sstate-cache is updated regardless of which branch was used to run bitbake.
This means that any successful build updates the sstate-cache that is used for all CI builds. So if the CI run on a temporary/experimental branch that updates a lot of packages, then the sstate-cache is updated accordingly and if the next build does not use the same version of packages, it is much slower and once again updates the sstate-cache with its version of the packages.
I am wondering what is the best practise to update the sstate-cache in this scenario?

sstate-cache is something to be not touched manually, the Yocto build system will automatically manage the sstate-cache. In your case, even if it gets updated when you run it on temporary branch, when you move back to the original branch all the changes from the temp branch should be stale and Yocto will automatically discard them.

This is the cache for a CI server. We back it up and restore it on every build. We have to keep it up to date for it to be useful. We have to update it when we make changes to our image. After some thinking I’m erring towards updating it each time a PR merged into main branch.  It wondering how others are doing it.

@Vincentz To me this question is unclear. Which steps exactly are an "update" to your sstate-cache? I'm with rakib_, you shouldn't touch the sstate-cache, apart from a weekly clean job, maybe.

My thinking is that we need to keep the cache in sync with the changes we make to our image to avoid it from missing packages added to our image.
The update is done via rsync, after a successful build.


Blockquote
This means that any successful build updates the sstate-cache that is used for all CI builds. So if the CI run on a temporary/experimental branch that updates a lot of packages, then the sstate-cache is updated accordingly and if the next build does not use the same version of packages, it is much slower and once again updates the sstate-cache with its version of the packages.

I believe there is wrong assumption/observation here.
Assumption is: when building from branch main, and then branch feature, then sstate-cache will contain artifacts of branch feature.
True is: it will hold artifacts from both branch main and feature. The next re-builds speed should be (almost) same, for both branches. after merging of feature into main, building of main will reuse artifacts generated by building feature before.
The difference of build time, that I have never noticed, maybe due to the bigger size of sstate-cache.
The procedure I do, and it works good in my opinion is:

share sstate-cache among all branches,
sstate-cache can be shared via nfs between several build-machines, even for concurrent builds, it works nice.
share sstate-cache among projects with same MACHINE (option, but makes sense).
share DL_DIR among all projects.
periodically run build without SSATE_DIR, and DL_DIR, just to make sure everything can still be downloaded and built.

If you want to clean up, (eg. after yocto update), just change the directory name temporarily, do rebuild (let sstate-cache be filled again), and if it works, remove old directory.
